# Fast algorithm for uniformity test

Tags: algorithm, statistics, uniform

I have zero to many bookings per day, and I need some measure of how uniformly these bookings are distributed throughout my time period. Bookings can be half day or full day bookings.

The time period I am considering in this case is one month.

My data has lots of gaps: in a month I may only have up to 25-50% of days booked.

I need an algorithm which will give me a number (arbitrary units, I don't care: I will just be comparing many permutations and picking the most uniform) which represents the uniformity of the bookings.

Most importantly, I need it to be quite fast as I will be running it many hundreds of times.

I have looked at Anderson-Darling tests, Cramer-con-Mises, and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests, but these all check whether data fits *any* distribution. I'm sure there is a faster algorithm to determine if data is purely uniform.

I'm coding in C#

Comment: If you only care about the relative ordering of "uniformity" you could find the RMS of the gaps in between bookings.  A truly uniform distribution should have the lowest RMS (assuming fixed number of bookings over fixed amount of time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am not grossly oversimplifying your question but I believe all you really want to know is the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of your gaps. There are a [set of algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) for calculating variance, each with their own properties and all of which are pretty fast.

Comment: Yes, this is the method I am currently using. I was hoping there was an algorithm which uses some mathematical property which allows us to rapidly move through the data points computing the gaps and variances in a single loop.